# Django REST Framework: overriding get_queryset() sometimes returns a doubled queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a little endpoint, adapting DRF `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`, defined as follows:

```
class MyApi(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    queryset = []
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print 'Debug: I am starting...\n\n\n\n'
        # do a lot of things filtering data from Django models by some information on neo4j and saving data in the queryset...
        return self.queryset
```

When I call `MyApi` via URL, it returns results without any problems, but sometimes it returns doubled result!! It's very strange...It's not a systematic error but happens only sometimes.

I use the line `print 'Debug: I am starting...\n\n\n\n'` in Apache log to investigate the problem. When that doubling happens, I read in the log:

```
Debug: I am starting...




Debug: I am starting...
```

It seems like `get_queryset` is called more than one time. It's very strange. I didn't report the detail of the logic inside that method, I think the problem is elsewhere or that is a bug...How can I solve?

Comment: paste your whole view for better idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have defined `queryset` as a class attribute.

```
class MyApi(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = []
```

That means that each time you append to `self.queryset`, you are appending to the same list. Your `get_queryset` method is only called once, but `self.queryset` already has entries in it at the beginning of the method. To see the problem in action, `print self.queryset` in your method at the very beginning, before you change it.

You would be better to do something like:

```
class MyApi(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = None  # this line is probably not required, but some code checking tools like it to be defined.

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.queryset = []
        ...
        return self.queryset
```

Comment: Ok, any ideas about the reason why it does not happen systematically after every call?

Comment: Your Apache deployment will have Django running in multiple processes. Requests handled in on process will not affect other processes, and every so often processes are probably killed and restarted.

Comment: Ok it works very fine. I stil don't understand why self.queryset has already entries in it before the first call, if a process don't affect the others.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have shown that would cause duplicate results on the first request after the server started, you would only get duplicates on subsequent requests.

Comment: That sounds strange for my basic knowledge of Python, Django and Apache. I don't understand how self.queryset may have entries before first call, if I defined it as an empty list

Comment: You define it as empty list as class attribute. Since in Python classes are singletons, when you append to it, you are appending to a class attribute hence future instances of the class will have those values as well until the thread is restarted.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a custom permission like **DjangoModelPermissions**. You need to check that the `get_queryset` method of your **View** is not being called.

For example, [DjangoModelPermissions](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L116-L119) call this method [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L117):

```
if hasattr(view, 'get_queryset'):
    queryset = view.get_queryset()
else:
    queryset = getattr(view, 'queryset', None)
```

If I use this permission just as it is. The method `get_queryset` will be called twice.

So I changed it to just this:

```
queryset = getattr(view, 'queryset', None)
```

As a result it is just called once. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `queryset = []` as class attributes and class attributes are "shared by all instances". So, if you python process append some data to your `queryset` attribute, the subsequent view instances would have that data, only if they are created by the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and just ran a trackback
Turns out that the second run is the rest_framework's rendering files calling view.get_queryset().

Try calling it from the command line and then checking the results.